# MongoDB tabularize nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Given the document of the following structure:

```
{
    username: "John",
    subjects: [
        {subjectName: "subjectA", status : "PASSED" },
        {subjectName: "subjectB", status : "PASSED" },
        {subjectName: "subjectC", status : "FAILED" }
    ]
},
{
    username: "Jason",
    subjects: [
        {subjectName: "subjectA", status : "PASSED" },
        {subjectName: "subjectB", status : "PASSED" },
        {subjectName: "subjectC", status : "FAILED" }
    ]
}
```

How can I get all the passed subjects in the following format?

```
[{username: "John", subjectName: "subjectA", status : "PASSED"},
{username: "John", subjectName: "subjectB", status : "PASSED"},
{username: "Jason", subjectName: "subjectA", status : "PASSED"},
{username: "Jason", subjectName: "subjectB", status : "PASSED"}]
```

Comment: are you trying using a programming language like java or directly trying to query?

Comment: @PrasadKharkar I'm using javascript with Mongoose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `aggregation` like this :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
    "$unwind": "$subjects"
}, {
    "$match": {
        "subjects.status": "PASSED"
    }
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$username"
        , "subjects": {
            "$push": "$subjects"
        }
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": "$subjects"
}, {
    "$project": {
        "_id": 0
        , "username": "$_id"
        , "subjectName": "$subjects.subjectName"
        , "status": "$subjects.status"
    }
})
```

But In this aggregation `unwind` creates a multiple documents and in large array size it creates problem so you should use [redact](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) like this :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
"$match": {
    "subjects.status": "PASSED"
}
}, {
"$redact": {
    "$cond": {
        "if": {
            "$eq": [{
                "$ifNull": ["$status", "PASSED"]
            }, "PASSED"]
        },
        "then": "$$DESCEND",
        "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
}
}).pretty()
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need a simple aggregation query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$subjects"},
    {$match: {"subjects.status": "PASSED"}},
    {$project: {username: 1, subjectName: "$subjects.subjectName", status: "$subjects.status"}}
]);
```

Comment: suppose the subject array is large, and I have plenty of documents, would `$unwind` cause performance problems?